# After using callback in react its not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I have an Ajax call `_getSingleContract` from this I am invoking API

```
export function _getSingleContracts(data, callback) {

    let token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    let url = "/contracts/read?access_token=" + token;
    let BASE = "http://172.14.136.4:1082"
    let actualurl = BASE + url;

    Api._callAPI(actualurl, 'GET', data, (type, dt) => {
        if (type == 'success') {
            dispatcher.dispatch({
                type: 'SingleContract',
                data: dt,
            })
            callback(dt);
        }
    });
}
```

From the `_getSingleContract` I am making a callback but still I cannot able to call `_generatePDF` function

```
_getSingleContract(id) {

    let data = {
        id: this.state.cell.row,
    };
    ContractAction._getSingleContracts(data, function(data) {
        console.log(data.contract.html);
        let data1 = data.contract.html;
        ContractAction._generatePDF(data1);
    });
}
```

Please anyone guide me in using callback.

Comment: r u getting any error ???

Comment: no, I am not getting any errror and not calling ContractAction._generatePDF(data1); also

Comment: console log is logging something ???

Comment: no its not coming inside

Comment: put a console log in api callback and console type is success or not and then try to keep callback above dispatch

Comment: can you provide email so that can discuss in hangouts instead of long chat here

Comment: Seems like you miss the crucial part in the debugging experience - console.logs and debugger statements.

Comment: s.shubhanu.s@gmail.com